# How often are GSMaP and IMERG in Google Earth Engine updated?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I am trying to get a near-real-time data from Google Earth Engine for Hourly Precipitation. How often are the GSMaP and IMERG updated?

At what time (UTC) will new data become available? Below is an example of the latest available images from IMERG and GSMaP obtained on May 18th 06.00 UTC

[image: Latest available images in Google Earth Engine obtained on May 18th 06.00 UTC]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can determine latency from image metadata by differencing the `'system:version'` date property from the `'system:time_start'` date property.

- `'system:version'` represents the time the data were ingested into the Earth Engine Data Catalog in units of microseconds since Unix epoch.
- `'system:time_start'` represents the time the data were collected in units of milliseconds since Unix epoch.

Here is an example for calculating mean latency (hours) over the last two months of GSMaP data:

```js
// #############################################################################
// ### INPUTS ###
// #############################################################################

var COL_ID = "JAXA/GPM_L3/GSMaP/v6/operational";
var PERIOD = 2;  // Today to PERIOD months prior

// #############################################################################


function calcLatency(img) {
  var version = img.get('system:version');
  var ingest = ee.Date(ee.Number(version).divide(1000));
  var observe = img.date();
  var latency = ingest.difference(observe, 'hours');
  return img.set('latency', latency);
}

var col = ee.ImageCollection(COL_ID);
var today = ee.Date(Date.now());

col = col.filterDate(today.advance(-PERIOD, 'months'), today)
  .map(calcLatency);

var meanLatency = col.reduceColumns({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    selectors: ['latency']
}).get('mean');

print('Mean latency (hours) for last ' + PERIOD + ' months:',
      meanLatency);
```

*This should only be used for recent streaming data that has been collected and ingested within the last few months since present.*

Answer (score 0):

> How often are data in EE updated?
>
> Normally, all ongoing datasets are updated at least daily (though not all such datasets have new data every day). Some datasets are updated several times a day. However, there is no policy to guarantee the presence of the most recent assets in the catalog.

— https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/faq#how_often_are_data_in_ee_updated